# Facebook, login reload loop

Tags: facebook, heroku

There is some unknown problem with my facebook app running on heroku

Problem is now something with the access token. Im not sure what
It seems like something in the app corrupts my access token. Cause when I attempt to login to the app, and then use the explorer it says that im either logged out or the acces token is expired. but if I debug it, it says its valid for 2 more hours.
Also, the page fails to reload after I have logged in.

Aparently the site keeps reloading.. and updating over and over. This stops when logged in on the page

The error seems to have occured recently.. Didn't have it last week. Im guessing the problem would lie somewhere here, but I can't find it.
If you see anything that could give a problem please hint it out. Thanks

```
require_once('sdk/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(), 
'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(), 
'sharedSession' => true,
'trustForwarded' => true,
));

$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user_id) {
 try {
  // Fetch the viewer's basic information
    $basic = $facebook->api('/me');
 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  // If the call fails we check if we still have a user. The user will be
// cleared if the error is because of an invalid accesstoken
 if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
  header('Location: '. AppInfo::getUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
  exit();
 }
}

 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
    });

   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log (response.status);
    //this is useful if you want to avoid the infinite loop bug
    //it only reloads page when you log in
    if (response.status != 'connected') {
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            // We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
            // Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
            // window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
            // post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
            // user asking if they want to send data again.
            window.location = window.location;
            //Im using the window.location.reload()
            //window.location.reload();
        });
    }
});
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
 };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<header class="clearfix">
  <?php if (isset($basic)) { ?>
  <p id="picture" style="background-image: url(https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo he($user_id); ?>/picture?type=normal)"></p>

  <div>
    <h1>Welcome, <strong><?php echo he(idx($basic, 'name')); ?></strong></h1>
    <p class="tagline">
      This is your new app for sorting events
      <a href="<?php echo he(idx($app_info, 'link'));?>" target="_top"><?php echo he($app_name); ?></a>
    </p>

    <div id="share-app">
      <p>Share this app:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-button" id="postToWall" data-url="<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>">
            <span class="plus">Post to Wall</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-button speech-bubble" id="sendToFriends" data-url="<?php echo AppInfo::getUrl(); ?>">
            <span class="speech-bubble">Send Message</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="facebook-button apprequests" id="sendRequest" data-message="Prøv den her">
            <span class="apprequests">Send Requests</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="user_likes,user_photos,user_events,friends_events, user_hometown,user_location,user_interests,user_about_me,user_education_history,friends_location,read_friendlists"></div> 
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</header>
<section id="get-started">
 <?php 
 //echo (idx($app_get_events[1], 'id');
 ?>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what browser are you using? New Safari versions don't accept cookies from iframes. So please check if the session is working properly, and if you can create cookies.

Comment: hi, im using firefox on w7 :)

Comment: and what about session? is it working properly? Are you able to create cookies?

Comment: Not sure how to check it Mark :/ Should I just try to set some other cookie or just do a print_r on it?

Comment: Tried to add window.top.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/MYAPP'  - No succes ofc myapp was replaced with my appnamespace

Comment: set some session variables, and read them. Create some cookies, and do a "print_r" on it :)

Comment: Sometimes the site crashes totally(exeption 100 the parameter queries is required\n) and returns an error on line 1238 in facebook_base.php which looks like this -> $e = new FacebookApiException($result); which to me looks like, there just is some oAuthexception which has nothing really to do with the looping.. So far no problems with setting a cookie. Not sure which session variables to use, could you give me an example ? :)

Comment: FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         console.log (response.status);
   if (response.status != 'connected') { Fixed the reloading.. but now the login button disapeared

Comment: Ok button now appears correctly. Now its the oauth dialog which instantly closes down when you press the button

Comment: Problem seems to be the access token now. something bugs up. When I log in on the page, it dosent reload. but if I manually reload it, and then use the api explorer tool, it will say that my access token has expired. then I have to clear it in the explorer to get the explorer to work again (the access token debugger dosent find anything) Really down to 0 clues now where this fault is triggered.